# UIWebView inside block with dispatch_get_main_queue gives another object (0X0000ecf0)

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview, objective-c-blocks

I've got a question about objects in blocks. I have a UIWebView that I want to update after a call to an object that retrieves data with Core Data. The method has a callback and inside it I want to call the UIWebView, webView. This doesn't work because the object inside the block is another than the one outside. I've tried to resolve this by doing a dispatch_get_main_queue() but it doesn't matter.

How do I update the webView from inside the block?

```
 //UIWebView object, webView, in an UIView on main thread
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCommand];

[object getDataWithManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext withCallback:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSString *functionCall = "call()";
         //I want this UIWebView object, webView, to be the same as in the main thread
         [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:functionCall];
     });
 }
 ];
```

Help is really appreciated.
Daniel

Comment: It is the same one. What do you mean by it's not the same one? Also, what isn't working?

Comment: are you sure that, by the time your callback block is called, you haven't replaced your instance-level UIWebView with another, different instance, somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @mattjgalloway When I debug the code I can see that the pointer is not equal.
Thank you

Comment: @magma I'm almost sure about it but I will investigate one more time to be totally sure.
Thank you